# Android: understand this.context

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to understand a class  responsible to make a connection to a **DB**
the code is:

```
    public class DBAdapter 
    {

        final Context context;

        DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
        SQLiteDatabase db;

        public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
        {
            this.context = ctx;
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
        {
            DatabaseHelper(Context context)
            {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }
            //All the necessary method are implemented.
        }

}
```

So to make a conection i should just"

```
DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);
```

My question is what does this line `this.context = ctx;` does:

Why we can not omit that and simply :

```
public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
        {
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your class code. you does not required to assign context to another context variable . this is simplified code.

```
 public class DBAdapter 
    {

        DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
        SQLiteDatabase db;

        public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
        {
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
        }

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
        {
            DatabaseHelper(Context context)
            {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }
            //All the necessary method are implemented.
        }

}
```

To assign context to another variable is useful when you use context in some other methods as well. because the scope of the variable is limited to its method. you cannot use it outside of the constructor(according to your code)

Answer (score 1):

Through this keyword you are specifying that the address or the reference of activity class which is coming to the DBAdapter method in ctx variable which is of Context type will be assigned to class level Context variable.

Though you can remove class level variable and `this.context = ctx;` line and simply write as you had specified

```
 public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
        {
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
        }
```

but if you want to use ctx (context reference) value to all over class it is advised to use class variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the tutorial, they have a Context class variable because they reference it in the open method.

```
public DbAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.mCtx = ctx;
    mUsername = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(Preferences.USERNAME, "");
}

public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me the link of documentations pleas?